# How can i attach an image to a button instead of setting a text in JavaFX? [NO FXML]

Tags: java, javafx, project

I am new to JavaFX and i am currently working on a project (in which i can't use fxml).
I would like to create a button that would display an image, like a search icon.
I will provide an image to be specific:

[image: search icon button]

Any suggestions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: `button.setGraphic(new ImageView(...));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in your question...

> I am new to JavaFX

Then I suggest finding a tutorial. I think it is better than posting questions here to which you will find the answers in a good tutorial. I recommend [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html).

The following code produces the GUI in the image you linked to. Note that the file containing the image, *search.png*, must be located in the same directory as the file `ButonImg.class`, i.e. the file created when you compile the below code. I suggest reading the *javadoc* for the [JavaFX] classes and methods in the below code to learn and understand how they work. The *javadoc* is available online and can be easily found by searching, for example if you search for the words **javafx hbox**

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButonImg extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label("City");
        TextField txtFld = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button();
        Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("search.png"));
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
        button.setGraphic(imgView);
        HBox root = new HBox(10.0d, label, txtFld, button);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20.0d, 20.0d, 20.0d, 20.0d));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the GUI displayed when running the above code.

[image: butonimg.png]